# tableView renders slowly with UIImages

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, tableview

I have a custom cell that populates the tableView with users post on the app. The user can post a text message or a text message with a uiimage.

The initial problem i had was in setting the height of the cell when i contained an images. I ended up having image sin the tableview cells with ridiculous height and the images were not loading correctly.

so i added the code below to the tableView CellforRowAt function, in order to alter the frame of the images so that the UIImages loaded in a uniform size. Although this is working perfectly now, when i scroll on the tableview it is super glitchy and slow. I assume its because of the frame being altered and it takes a while to process this new frame. Is it possible to make this more efficient and smoother?

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
       if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
            cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.commentDelegate = self
            cell.likeDelegate = self
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            let imageIndex = posts[indexPath.row].mediaURL
            let url = NSURL(string: imageIndex)! as URL
            if let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
               let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                let newWidth = cell.MediaPhoto.frame.width
                let scale = newWidth/image!.size.width
                let newHeight = image!.size.height * scale
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
                image!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
                    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                    cell.MediaPhoto.image = newImage
                cell.MediaPhoto.contentMode = .scaleToFill
                cell.MediaPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
        return cell
        
    }
```

Comment: Probably the whole `URL` things. It has to keep getting the data from the URL which takes time. I'd recommend to get all the images at once and store them in a `UIImage` array

Comment: Ok, thats sounds like a good idea. What do you suggest is the best way to implement this?

Comment: look if this is big list of image then you should school it local data storage using realm or core data. And if this is the small bunch of list then you can just store the images at once in any variable then you can load them locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this code to fix the image size to be 400 x 400 and it worked great. It doesn't render slowly or glitch anymore.

```
func set(post:Posts) {
    
    self.post = post
    
    // get PROFILE image
    let url = post.url
    profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
    
    // get MEDIA image
    let mediaString = post.urlM.absoluteString
    if mediaString == "none" {
        MediaPhoto.image = nil
    } else {
        let mediaUrl = post.urlM
        MediaPhoto.sd_setImage(with: mediaUrl, completed: nil)
        
        //RESIZE MEDIA PHOTO
        let itemSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let imageRect : CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: itemSize.width, height: itemSize.height)
        MediaPhoto!.image?.draw(in: imageRect)
        MediaPhoto!.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the work outside of the main thread.

```
     class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var image: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
func set(post: Post) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            let strongSelf = self!
            if let url = NSURL(string: strongSelf.mediaUrl) as URL?,
                let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
                
                strongSelf.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
               
            
        }
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let image = image else { super.draw(rect) }
    let newWidth = MediaPhoto.frame.width
    let scale = newWidth/image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
   
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    MediaPhoto.image = newImage
    MediaPhoto.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    MediaPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.commentDelegate = self
    cell.likeDelegate = self
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
}
return cell
```

}

Comment: When i do this i get the error 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' next to the code let scale = newWidth/image!.size.width

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, the first draw will be nil. Just guard let image = image first